# Why does Haunt (Consuming Spirit) Slow?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

I am using [Haunt](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/witch-doctor/active/haunt) with the Consuming Spirit rune. When I cast this on an enemy, the word "Slowed" appears next to the enemy. Why is this?

Character profile on battle.net is [here](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/profile/SabreWolfy-1656/hero/28988691).

Comment: Can you link your bnet profile ? I'm guessing that's because you have a weapon or mojo with %chance of chilling

Comment: I thought of that and checked carefully, but I'll add a link.

Comment: Also, the "Slowed" text is displayed only when using Haunt. Could it be as a result of the Cold damage, which Haunt does?

Comment: that's quite easy to test, use another rune that does not deal cold damage and see if slow still applies. On the Game Guide elemental damage are not displayed so I didnt think of that but yes cold skills slow targets.

Comment: All of Haunt's runes deal cold damage. The Grasping Spirit rune (Level 48; I'm in the low 40's now) specifically slows enemies by 60%. This is why I was surprised that the Consuming Spirit rune *also* slows enemies.

Comment: Haunt's Resentful Spirit and Lingering Spirit also show "Slowed" on hitting an enemy.

Comment: If you want to be absolutely sure : go naked (no items and skills except haunt) and haunt : see if it slows. Make the same test with another skills that uses cold damage : see if it slows. If yes and yes then you have your answer, if there is a no somewhere then there might be another game mechanic at work

Comment: Yeah, I might try that on my *softcore* Witch Doctor, not on the hardcore one I am playing at present :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All Haunt runes deal Cold damage, which has a secondary effect of chilling ([slowing](http://www.diablowiki.net/Cold_Damage)) enemies.

The curiosity of the "Grasping Spirits" (also) slowing enemies is noted [here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12404630355).

Comment: The Gargantuan Humongoid rune, which deals Cold damage, does *not* result in "Slowed" text appearing when the pet strikes an enemy.